# docker networking with traefik: publishing ports necessary in some cases?

Tags: docker, ejabberd, traefik, docker-network

I run traefik as proxy for many containers successfully.

I also run a dockered *prosody* (XMPP-server) with published ports (5222 and 5269) in the traefik network.
As I want it to work with strict TLS and no STARTTLS I use HostSNI-rule and tcp instead of http protocol in traffic for labeling, I passthrough the tls because it is terminated in xmpp instance itself (not *traefik*). I place the certificates there. It works.

Soon I realize I might have done it all wrong: since I want to compare it with a second XMPP service (*ejabberd*) behind *traefik*, a port conflict (5222 and 5269 already in use) makes me wonder why I mapped the ports at all on a bridged network with *traefik* in first instance?
So I disabled them for *prosody* (no ports, no expose in docker-compose file of *prosody*). But now it can't be reached anymore although I have set the labels and service for traefik rules accordingly. (In Portainer>Inspect>Networksettings>ports show they are recognized, available in image).

1. First conclusion: I think traffic is not going over traefik at all (as local dns points to the docker host with the published ports). But if I stop traefik, xmpp clients won't connect with published ports neither. So then it must still go via traefik proxy, right?. How can one check/probe that actually? Why do I need the ports being exposed/published (I tried all of it) in docker in the use-case to work solely with traefik?
2. I decided to let *prosody* be with strict TLS (as is, including mapped ports which makes no sense to me) and enable STARTTLS with *ejabberd* and adding new entry-points for port 5221 and 5268 including mapping them in traefik. But no success for connection - what do I miss in the concept? (as standalone *ejabberd* container works well):

```
 labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.xmpp2-c2c.entrypoints=xmpp2"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.xmpp2-c2c.rule=Host(`local.lan`)"
      #- "traefik.tcp.routers.xmpp2-c2c.rule=HostSNI(`local.lan`)"
      #- "traefik.tcp.routers.xmpp2-c2c.tls=true"
      #- "traefik.tcp.routers.xmpp2-c2c.tls.passthrough=true"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.xmpp2-c2c.service=xmpp2-c2c-service"
      - "traefik.tcp.services.xmpp2-c2c-service.loadbalancer.server.port=5222"
```

3. Why should I use traefik at all then? Maybe I should put them (XMPP servers) not behind a reverse-proxy as it is missing the primary goal for serving different services at the same domain (tls termination). But for the sake of comprehension I still expect it to work with traefik - or is there anything else I forgot to think about?